# No puedo publicar una PWA

Tags: blazor

Blazor es nuevo para mi, desarrollé un proyecto PWA en blazor webassembly el cual tiene tres partes el .client, .server y .Shared , al correr el proyecto funciona pero al publicarlo en un servidor real en ambiente productivo solo puedo acceder a la web api, al publicar hice click derecho en proyecto .server opción Publicar, Pero no logro acceder a la pagina de inicio de mi proyecto tal como funciona al debuguear.

He intentado e investigado de como se publica en IIS el .server pero en mi servidor real no me funciona, he intentado publicar el proyecto .client pero me marca el siguiente error y no se si hay una forma de unir ambos proyectos .server y .client.

La operación de publicación detectó un error.
Error de compilación. Compruebe la ventana de salida para obtener más detalles.

Se ha creado un registro de diagnóstico en la siguiente ubicación:
"C:\Users\userApp\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp31CF.tmp"

Comment: 1.- Tu dices que funciona el API pero blazor no se despliega??? confirma. 2.- Agrega un ejemplo de la URL. 3.- Agrega que te aparece en el navegador cuando ingresas a esa URL (incluido la consola)

Comment: https://miurl.me/serviciosweb/wsAppPedimentosBlazorProductivo/api/Pedimentos, esta es mi url y pues hago llamada en este caso al controlador de la web api y me regresa el json del unico metodo GET pero intento con https://masterchoice.perfectchoice.me/serviciosweb/wsAppPedimentosBlazorProductivo/Index.razor o https://masterchoice.perfectchoice.me/serviciosweb/wsAppPedimentosBlazorProductivo/Index.html y no obtengo resultados solo error 404. y lo que pretendo es que me muestre la vista y de ahi poder usar el metodo post que tengo, gracias por contestar.

Answer (score 0):

Debes ir al "index.html" que está en el proyecto `client/wwwroot` y editar el elemento `base` que está en el header

Tiene que verse de esta manera

```
<base href="/serviciosweb/wsAppPedimentosBlazorProductivo/" />
```

***OJO: debe empezar y terminar con una barra invertida -> `/`***

Tu tienes

```
<base href="/" />
```

Esto indica que la aplicación se encuentra en la raíz y todos los assets que carga por el services worker (incluyendo el wasm) los va a buscar teniendo eso en cuenta, y como no es así...pues no carga